# Error occurred when retrieving data from cassandra in spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using Spark-Cassandra-Connector-assembly-2.0.0-M1-13-gd0df0.jar in Spark 2.0.0. I'm connecting to spark-shell:

```
bin/spark-shell --jars jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-2.0.0-M1-13-gd0df0.jar
```

When I try to retrieve data from cassandra, I'm getting the following error:

```
scala> sc.stop

scala> import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkContext._, org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

scala> val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
conf: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@a9a8ec3

scala> val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@6451a288

scala> val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test_spark", "test")
test_spark_rdd: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow] = CassandraTableScanRDD[0] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15

scala> test_spark_rdd.first
16/08/16 15:02:19 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.<init>(CountingIterator.scala:4)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.compute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:336)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 10 more
16/08/16 15:02:19 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-0,5,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.<init>(CountingIterator.scala:4)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.compute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:336)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 10 more
16/08/16 15:02:19 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.<init>(CountingIterator.scala:4)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.compute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:336)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 10 more

16/08/16 15:02:19 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/08/16 15:02:19 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerStageCompleted(org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo@12164ec5)
16/08/16 15:02:19 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerJobEnd(0,1471384939706,JobFailed(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.<init>(CountingIterator.scala:4)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.compute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:336)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 10 more

Driver stacktrace:))
```

After this error message the scala prompt closes automatically.

Cassandra version: 3.0.8
Scala version: 2.11.8

In cassandra.yaml:
native_transport_port: 9042
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In all likelihood, this is because your jars are not compiled with Scala 2.11. Have you tried building assembly jars against 2.11 using `sbt -Dscala-2.11=true assembly` as suggested by the [docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/12_building_and_artifacts.md)